# Derive simplicity of left-turning polygonal curves

Tags: geometry, optimization, computational-geometry

Consider a polygonal curve $P$ consisting of a sequence of vertices $(p_1,…, p_n)$. The curve is not closed, meaning that $p_1 ≠ p_n$. The curve has the property that each vertex makes left-turn, that is, orient $(p_{i-1},p_i,p_{i+1}) > 0$, for $2 ≤ i ≤ n−1$ (*see Fig.*).

The problem is to design an efficient algorithm (ideally running in $O(n)$ time) that determines whether $P$ is simple, meaning that no two nonadjacent edges of $P$ intersect one another (*see Fig.(a) and (b)*).

[image: Left-polygonal curves]

Now actually a problem: for $2 ≤ i ≤ n−1$, define $\theta_i$ be the counterclockwise angle from the directed vector $v_{i-1}→v_i$ to $v_i→v_{i+1}$. The turning number of $P$, denoted $turn(P)$, is defined to be
$$turn(P) := \sum_{i=2}^{n-2}\frac{\theta_i}{2\pi}.$$
I need to derive an algorithm for testing the simplicity of $P$, assuming that $turn(P) ≤ 1$.
That is, the curve cannot make a spiral.

I know from Preparata, Shamos p.172-173 of a problem called *DEPTH OF A SET*. So this problem finds a "depth" of every point $p$ in set -- number of convex hulls, made for our points, which have to be stripped from our set of points before $p$ is removed. Better to show an image:
[image]

So I think I could use here that? Because it seems **simple** curves have depth of points of the curve equal to one, when **self-intersecting** seems to have number equal more than one.

Any ideas how to solve this? Maybe I need an another approach?

Comment: Why don't you test that for each new $p_{i+1}$, line segment $(p_{i},p_{i+1})$ has no common point with any of the already constructed $(p_{k},p_{k+1})$ (for $k=1...(i-2)$) ? But this is O(n^2)... It will remain the case of the spiral that ought to be treated apart.

Comment: Your claim about connection between simplicity and depth looks wrong - it's easy to create a self-intersecting  polyline with four vertices, all of them are on its convex hull

Comment: Also turning number less than one will still allow you to create a spiral - just choose very small angle between segments and decreasing with $i$ length of each segment

Comment: @HEKTO, seems right

Comment: @HEKTO, strange, the claim about connectivity turn value and being a spiral was given

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just some insight. If you consider growing the polygon until a certain vertex, the allowed area for the next vertex is the visibility graph of the current vertex (in white in the two examples below and using the fact that the turn is only left).

It is possible that the update of the visibility graph can be made incrementally, with a constant amortized time per vertex (?). Anyway, it is dubious that testing the next vertex against this graph can also be done in constant amortized time.

[image]

Comment: but it seems fastest visibility graph constructing takes $O(n^2 \log n)$...